# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Tags: java

I can't figure out what the problem is someone please help. The program is supposed to find the index of the duplicate values in the array and print these out. Outputs java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10.

```
private static String s = "";
private static int num = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 3, 7, 1, 9, 3 };
    for (int i = 1; i <= array.length; ++i) {
        while (num <= array.length - 2 && array[num] == array[i]) {
            s += i + ","; 
            num += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("index 0 are at positions" +s);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: The time you spent writing this question would have been better spent typing "java array index out of bounds exception" in google. The top 10 hits have exactly the same problem you're having here.

Comment: A length of ten means yourArray[0 - 9]  position ZERO is the FRIST one, position 1 is the SECOND.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int i= 0; i<array.length; ++i) {
    while (num <=array.length-2 && array[num]==array[i]) {
        s += i+ ","; 
        num += 1;
    }
}
```

This should work for you. length of array is `10`, so last index is `9`, not `10`! And start from `0`!

Answer (score 4):

`array.length` is `10`, but last index in array is `9`, because array index start from `0`.

The stop condition in your `for` loop should be `i<=array.length-1` if you want to loop through entire array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should start from 0 instead of index 1. And secondly you should use < sign

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the max number of elements is set to `10` which means the index number would start at `0`.

You can only get element until the `9`th element.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
```

It is clear sign, that you're not having an `11`th element.

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
    while (num <= array.length - 2 && array[num] == array[i]) {
        s += i + ","; 
        num += 1;
    }
}
```

This would do the job for you.

Comment: thanks for the help but the above code doesn't print the index of the array at repeat positions. It prints :index 0 are at positions0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,